Masqueraded response is wrong?
Description
My goal is to ping Machine C (10.223.0.7) from Machine A (10.101.0.40)
I have 2 networks and 3 machines

Network A : 10.223.0.0/24

Network B : 10.101.0.0/16

Machine A (the "pinger") : 10.101.0.40 (on eth5)

Machine B (the "router") : 10.101.2.97 (on ens7) & 10.223.0.1 (on wg0)

Machine C (the "pinged") : 10.223.0.7 (on wg0)

I've enabled IP forward on Machine B, globally and on both interfaces ens7 and wg0

My firewall is ACCEPT(ing) FORWARD rules on Machine B.

I've added this rule : iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE on Machine B to enable masquerade

I've added this rule ip route add 10.223.0.0/24 via 10.101.2.97 dev eth5 on Machine A to route the packets


The test
When I launch the ping, this is what I can see with tcpdump -nni any icmp :
Machine A :
18:16:12.976724 eth5  Out  IP 10.101.1.40 > 10.223.0.7: ICMP echo request, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64

Machine B :
18:16:12.977241 ens7  In  IP 10.101.1.40 > 10.223.0.7: ICMP echo request, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64
18:16:12.977287 wg0   Out IP 10.223.0.1 > 10.223.0.7: ICMP echo request, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64
18:16:12.978201 wg0   In  IP 10.223.0.7 > 10.223.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64
18:16:12.978217 ens7  Out IP 10.223.0.7 > 10.101.1.40: ICMP echo reply, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64

Machine C
18:16:12.977754 wg0   In  IP 10.223.0.1 > 10.223.0.7: ICMP echo request, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64
18:16:12.977767 wg0   Out IP 10.223.0.7 > 10.223.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7373, seq 1065, length 64

And no response is coming back to Machine A.
I think the problem is in the 4th line of the log of Machine B. The SRC IP is 10.223.0.7 but in my opinion it should be 10.101.2.97, the IP of Machine B on the ens7 network. I have absolutely no clues on why this is this way.
I've tried to add this masquerade rule iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens7 -j MASQUERADE but as expected : this is not working.
Question
Why the masquerade is working on the request (see the 2nd line of Machine B) and not on the response (see the 4th line of Machine B) ?

I've reproduced this topology in a test environment (you can find the test setup here), and I can't reproduce the behavior you've reported: masquerading works as expected and machinea is able to successfully ping machinec. It looks like you may be using wireguard, and you haven't included your wireguard configuration in the question, so I haven't attempted to reproduce that aspect.

Wow I did not know about kathara, that's amazing. Thanks to your setup I discovered I was looking the wrong way. The logs were strictly identical, and it was working. Digging on why my MachineA was not receiving the reply, I discovered the OpenStack problem I explain in my answer.

Found it.
The line 4 looked strange to me but thanks to the setup of @larsks I realized it was fine.
The technology behind the ens7 network is openstack. And the private network was blocking the packets.
I've run these commands on my OpenStack bastion :
openstack port set --no-security-group a1a[...]669
openstack port set --disable-port-security a1a[...]669

With a1a[...]669 beeing the port ID corresponding to ens7 of MachineB
And right away, the ping was OK.
